# What is the value of the integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x^3}dx$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I tried to evaluate the integral

$$ \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2x)}{x^3}dx$$

using residues but the answer comes out to be a negative value, $-2 \pi$, which seems strange. Any help on how to calculate it properly?

Comment: Doesn't the integral diverge (to $\infty$)?

Comment: integral of $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is convergent. So should this one be too as the denominator decreases much faster here.

Comment: The problem is at the origin, not at infinity.

Comment: But the singularity at the origin isn't killed off by the sine.

Comment: But $|\frac{1}{x^3}| \gg |\frac{1}{x}|$ near $0$, which is where the problem is.

Comment: i got this result $4.92513\times 10^{96}$

Comment: Normally the method of residues is the way to go for integral like these. It can be shown that the divergence at origin is the only point which contributes to the integral and it contributes in a finite amount. So the convergence is not an all a issue. My problem is that I am getting the integral to be negative number. And this seems a bit strange. I really dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why do you think it only contributes to a finite amount? It looks like $\frac{1}{x^2}$ near the origin.

Comment: Well these things can be proved. Its a bit like dirac delta finction. Where the function itself is divergent but the integral remains finite.

Comment: But in that case $\sin$ is raised to the same power. So since $\sin(x)/x\approx 1$ near the origin, so is $\sin^4(x)/x^4$. I would like to see the proof that your integral is convergent, since [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bsin%282x%29%2Fx%5E3%2C%7Bx%2C-1%2C1%7D%5D) says it isn't.

Comment: That one converges because there is a fourth power of sine. It mollifies the singularity since sine is approximately $x$ near the origin. This is not the case here.

Comment: Along the bigger semicircular arc it will go to zero since the dinominator goes as $R^{3}$ and numerator remains bounded.

Comment: You cannot integrate a function on a path that passes through one of its poles, so you have to declare along which path the integral is considered.

Comment: Do you guys really know how to use residues to evaluate integrals? I am sorry but I would appreciate the views of people who already know the method. Discussions of how to manage paths along poles etc. Can be done somewhere else. Let us stick on the main issue that I am getting a negative value after the evaluation. Either someone should confirm that its either correct or describe the correct value.

Comment: If one integrates $\dfrac{e^{2iz}}{z^3}$ along the upper half of $|z|=R$ with a semicircular indent at the origin, the indent contributes
$$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{e^{i2\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{\epsilon^3e^{3i\theta}}i\epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta$$
which clearly blows up as $\epsilon\to0$.

Comment: i would be really interested how you get $-2\pi$. Which regularization method is used? Because even in principal value sense this integral doesn't exist...

Comment: Basically I say that $f(z)=\frac{e^{2iz}}{z^3}$ has a pole of order three at origin. So its residue is $\lim \limits_{z\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2}{dz^2}(z^3f(z)) = -2$ and then calculating the integral in usual way gives $-2\pi$.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculating the integral in [the] usual way"? If you avoid the pole by a small semicircular dent in the contour, then note that the integral over the small semicircle does not converge to a finite value as the radius shrinks to $0$, it con-/diverges to $\pm\infty$ (sign depends on whether the small semicircle is in the upper or lower half-plane).